# "Сечь (рубить) фишку" — откуда пошло выражение?

Tags: фразеология

Смекать, понимать, в чем дело — "сечь фишку". Это, конечно, сленговое выражение, но интересно было бы узнать, откуда оно пошло?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из тюремного арго, конечно. Вообще, ФИШКА в словаре арго даётся как многозначное слово: ФИШКА1- 1. обычно мн. Глаза. Чего фишаки навел? — что смотришь?2. обычно мн. Деньги. 3. из арм.Военное дежурство около караульной будки; караульная будка.4. Самое главное, суть, соль чего-л. Гляди в самую фишку. ♦ Фишку рубить (или срубать, сечь и т. п.) — разбираться в чем-л., догадываться, понимать, видеть суть дела.
http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/argo/53_14927

Сечь, рубить(арго) - понимать

Само выражение,возможно, из карточных пошло,  а может, из игры в кости или нарды, игровые кости тоже иногда фишками зовут. Сечь фишку – понимать все особенности чего-то .Там же, в играх, встречается и "секи","подсекай", "руби","подрубай", "срубай". Так что оттуда всё.