# Почему "рубят фишку"?

Tags: этимология, фразеология, жаргон

Есть такое выражение "рубить фишку" — то есть, разбираться в чем-то, что-то хорошо понимать.
Выражение приблатнённое, сленговое (интернет дает пометку: "из словаря молодёжного сленга", хотя, по-моему, молодёжь уже давно так не говорит).
Интересно узнать происхождение выражения.
Навскидку кажется, что оно пошло от картёжников или от игроков в рулетку: фишки используются там. Только почему же *фишку надо **рубить***?

Comment: Просто для сведения участников. Вот здесь еще имеется *похожий вопрос* (от этого же автора):  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/20164/%d0%a1%d0%b5%d1%87%d1%8c-%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%88%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5 ("Сечь (рубить) фишку" — откуда пошло выражение?). Может, надо объединить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Слово "рубить" на сленге само по себе означает "понимать", "разбираться в чем-то". А вот откуда это значение взялось и *какую такую **фишку рубят*** — вопрос далеко не очевидный.

Вряд ли — напрямую от "фишки" в казино. Выражение уж больно давнее, времён, когда народ с казино знаком был только по американским фильмам.
Рискну предположить, что тут не обошлось без картёжников, но немного в другом плане.

Фишками называли игральные карты (изначально, видимо, знаки мастей, но распространилось и на сами карты); а рубить — подрубать (колоду), т.е. производить съем (очень часто — шулерский) таким образом, чтобы карты жертвы были известны снимающему.
Это одна из версий, не более. Вообще-то такие выражения крайне редко поддаются однозначной интерпретации.

**Дополнение**
Мне подтвердили, что "рубить фишку" (вполне однозначно на языке картёжников) означает "подглядывать в чужие карты".
Не обязательно указанным способом, но это моей версии никак не противоречит.

Answer (score 4):

Согласно словарю ненормативной лексики, глагол "рубить" имеет два значения:
а) говорить, высказываться о чем-либо прямо и резко;
б) хорошо разбираться в чем-либо, быть сведущим.

*Костя вообще-то в математике **рубил** хорошо* (В. Шукшин).

Также ***рубиться, резаться*** — играть во что-то с большим АЗАРТОМ.
Скорее всего, переносное значение этих глаголов связано с энергичностью, направленностью и быстрой результативностью обозначаемых ими действий.

Поэтому "рубить фишку" — это  *разбираться в игорном деле.*

Из словаря арго:
Фишку рубить (или срубать, сечь и т. п.) — разбираться в чем-либо, догадываться, понимать, видеть суть дела.

Слово "фишка" является довольно популярным жаргонизмом. В переносном значении "фишка" – это особенность, сущность, характерная черта.

Answer (score 2):

Не уверен...
Но мне кажется, что тут идёт последовательное образование:
"капуста" **=** деньги;
"рубить капусту" **=** зарабатывать;
"рубить фишки" **=** зарабатывать фишки (в казино).

Умение заработать в игре подразумевает опыт или знание каких-то секретов:
***рубить фишки*** (фишку) = разбираться в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Фишкой называлась покрашенная в яркий цвет палочка, длиной в рост человека, которую втыкали в землю. Фишку новобранец в кавалерии должен был срубить на скаку при приеме на службу. Он или рубил фишку или нет. :))

Comment: Ну и в дальнейшем фишки использовали для тренировки, располагая из на разном расстоянии и с разных сторон от скачущей лошади. Кавалеристы тренировались в навыке срубить как можно больше фишек с разных сторон лошади с одного захода.